# Proof that this isn't a complete metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Given $d:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},d(x,y):=|e^{-x}-e^{-y}|$, $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is a, metric space (we don't have to prove this). Show that $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is not complete.
So the idea for my proof was:
Let $x_n:=n, n\in\mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of natural numbers. This sequence is a Cauchy-Sequence because let $\epsilon=N,N<n$
$|e^{-n}-e^{-m}|=e^{-n}-e^{-m}<e^{-n}<e^{-N}=\epsilon$
so
$\forall\epsilon>0\exists N_{\epsilon}\in\mathbb{N}\forall n,m>N_{\epsilon}:d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon$.

The second part is to show that $x_n$ doesn't converge in $(\mathbb{R},d)$:
Take a look at $e^{-n}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ which means for $\epsilon>0$, $|e^{-n}|<\epsilon\Leftrightarrow |e^{-n}-0|<\epsilon$ but $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:e^{-x}\neq 0$ which means that $x_n$ doesn't converge in this metric space. In conclusion $x_n$ is a Cauchy-Sequence that doesn't converge in $(\mathbb{R},d)$ which means that $(\mathbb{R},d)$ isn't a complete metric space.

I know that my proof is very poorly written but I'm not a native english speaker and therefore don't usually write proofs in english. Is this example right though and is this proof valid?

Comment: I think your proof is fine. At one place you have to add that $m>n.$ Concerning incompletness  I would rather write down the argument as follows $\lim_n d(x,n)=\lim_n|e^{-x}-e^{-n}| = e^{-x}>0.$  Hence the sequence $n$ has no accumulation points.

Comment: Okay thank you this seems reasonable!

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, but here are some points.

Where you write "let $\epsilon = N$" and "$e^{-N} = \epsilon$", you perhaps want to say "let $N$ be a natural number such that $e^{-N} < \epsilon$". For general $\epsilon > 0$ you cannot solve $e^{-N} = \epsilon$ for a natural number $N$, but you can always choose one large enough so that $e^{-N} < \epsilon$. You also want to specify $m \geq n$, so that $|e^{-n} - e^{-m}| = e^{-n} - e^{-m}$, instead of the other way around.

For the failure of convergence, I would argue by contradiction. Suppose there was some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} d(n, x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} |e^{-n} - e^{-x}| = 0$, which is to say $\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} = e^{-x}$ (in the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$). However, we know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} = 0$. The limit of a sequence in a metric space is unique, so we must have $e^{-x} = 0$ - but there is no such real number $x$.